# Trello attachment serving wrong Content-Type when attachment uploaded via the API

Tags: trello

I am using the Trello API to upload (and attach) files to a card.

I make a POST to https://api.trello.com/1/cards/my-card-id/attachments

Message body is JSON

```
{ file: file_contents, 'BuildSheet.html': filename, mimeType: 'text/html' }

file_contents is a string that contains the body of the file I want to attach.
```

That works. The file gets uploaded and attached. When I fetch the card data, this is what I see regarding this attachment.

```
{"id":"58a496bc751c0c2fa260630f",
 "bytes":3291,
 "date":"2017-0215T17:58:20.881Z",
 "edgeColor":null, 
 "idMember":"55240806b8ca85db897253c4",
 "isUpload":true,
 "mimeType":"text/html",
 "name":"BuildSheet.html",
 "previews":[],
 "url":"https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/589ca323806c1d80cc03ea12/589ceda619d5936e8428f15b/1f62074b6700e61e611a90beaa8c2c73/Upload"}
```

You can see that mimeType is set correctly. name is also correct. However the url doesn't use the filename like it does if you upload from inside the UI. So the file doesn't have a .html extension.

When I download the file, it contains this header

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

It should be text/html. This causes the browser to download the file instead of display it.

Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone else had this problem?

Additionally is there a way to get Trello to use the file name when it constructs the url?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the Trello API ignores the `mimeType` parameter, and instead uses the `Content-Disposition` parameter in the response body.

A body like the following works:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarydjg0lJJiuTZmCppw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

Here is the corresponding code, using the node request library:

```js
async function attachFileToTrelloCard(id: string, file: Buffer, fileName: string, mimeType: string) {
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://api.trello.com/1/cards/${id}/attachments`,
    formData: {
      file: {
        value: file,
        options: {
          filename: fileName,
          contentType: mimeType
        }
      },
      token: process.env.TRELLO_API_TOKEN,
      key: process.env.TRELLO_API_KEY,
      name: fileName,
      mimeType
    }
  }

  return await request(options)
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your filename has an extension in it. I had set filename to "Screenshot" and then preview didn't work. When I instead renamed it to "Screenshot.jpg" the preview worked. Feels like Trello is somehow reading the mimeType of the extension and maybe not taking the mimeType you provide into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

When I attach a file or url to a Trello card, I use POST with `url` only, like this (JavaScript):

```
var id = 'something';
var attach = 'https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html';

var payload = {"url": attach};
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(payload)], {type: 'application/json'});
var url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/cards/'+id+'/attachments?key='+API_KEY+'&token='+TOKEN;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.send(blob);
```

And after this when I get the JSON of the card, It's something like this:

```
{"id":"xxx...", ... 
 "actions":[{
   "id":"yyy...",
   "idMemberCreator":"...",
   "data":{
     "board":{ ...
     "attachment":{
       "url":"https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html",
       "name":"https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html",
       "id":"zzz..."}}, ...
```

You can get cards' JSON via adding `.json` at the end of the url. You can see `name` is the same as `url` but no `mimeType` here. And it's nowhere found in [the documentation](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#post-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-attachments). In which way did you 'fetch the card data?' If you use JavaScript, the above code maybe help you.

And as for customization of the url of cards, I don't know anything and I guess it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

> { file: file_contents, 'BuildSheet.html': filename, mimeType: 'text/html' }

Have you tried using the key `name`? [reference](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#post-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-attachments)